# IUP bullies Separator. Why?

Tags: iup

The IUP documentation specifies a GUI element called [Separator](https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/elem/iupseparator.html).

However it’s missing from the Available Classes list that pops up when you click Add Child / Add Brother in the [Layout Dialog](https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/dlg/iuplayoutdialog.html) (the IUP GUI layout editor).

[image: Separator is missing from Available Classes in the Layout Dialog]

Not only that, when you try to include Separator manually in a [LED file](https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/led.html) (as `SEPARATOR()` inside `VBOX()` or `HBOX()`) and then load it in the Layout Dialog and show it (or “map” it), you get the following error message:

> IupMap failed.

Subsequently, only the GUI elements that precede Separator are displayed. Why?

Part of the answer could be that “it shows a line between two **menu** items” (per documentation) whereas I have attempted to use it **outside menu** on dialog’s canvas (inside `VBOX()`). It can’t be a complete truth though because I have seen Separator being used outside menu in [GetParam](https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/dlg/iupgetparam.html) dialog (screenshot there). And even if it were, it still doesn’t explain why Separator is missing from Available Classes in the Layout Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IupSeparator is for menus only. That list is displayed to insert a new element inside the dialog.

The separator in IupGetParam is a IupLabel with the SEPARATOR attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile, I have found a functional **replacement** to [Separator](https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/elem/iupseparator.html) and it’s apparently [Label](https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/elem/iuplabel.html) with attribute `SEPARATOR` set to `HORIZONTAL`/`VERTICAL`/`YES`.

Example (LED):

```
FakeSeparatorDlg = DIALOG[TITLE = "IUP fake separator demo"](
  VBOX[MARGIN = 5x5,GAP = 5](
    LABEL[TITLE = "Label Text 1"](""),
    LABEL[SEPARATOR = HORIZONTAL](""),
    LABEL[TITLE = "Label Text 2"]("")
  )
)
```

[image: IUP fake separator demo]

Attribute `EXPAND = HORIZONTALFREE` will be added automatically.

Demo [`sample.c`](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/examples/C/sample.c) also includes an unexplained attribute `NAME = SAMP_SEP`.

The downside is lack of a visible title but I will simply use [Frame](https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/elem/iupframe.html) instead of Label when I need that.

#### Further reading

- IUP documentation: [IupLabel](https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/elem/iuplabel.html)
- thread [“divider line”](https://sourceforge.net/p/iup/mailman/message/33178986/) on a mailing list named `Iup-users`
- [“sample”](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/samples.html) ([C](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/examples/C/sample.c)/[LED](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/examples/LED/sample.led)/[Lua](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/examples/Lua/sample.lua)), as well as a compiled demo `iuptest(.exe)` that includes it ([download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iup/files/3.21/Tools%20Executables/), unzip, launch and choose “sample”)

Comment: Attribute `NAME` explained [here](https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/attrib/iup_name.html).